# how to register javaScript added dom objects in the browser's history

Tags: ajax, dom, refresh, back-button, browser-history

I have a page that displays a list of customers.  When the user adds a new customer, say "Susy", I have a ajax call that adds Susy into the database and then AjaxOnSuccess will add Susy to the DOM( with out refreshing the page ).

The problem I'm having is when the user navigates away from the page and then hits the back button Susy never appears... In order to get Susy to appear the userr needs to refresh the page.
    Is there a way to fix this or am I out of luck?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to add new entries to window.history. Over at [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) is an interesting article on how to manipulate the window.history object.

```
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
```

... is what you are looking for.

Comment: Interesting. I think that pushState(..) is currently not supported by all browsers. If that's that's the case I think I would like to use something else. Would "window.location = .." work for me?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not say much about browser compatibility of the MDN Article. However, with all the "ajax" frameworks out there it is certainly a problem that has been solved for all popular browsers. Maybe you should get help from one of those available JS frameworks.